# Letsencrypt on a non standard port?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I have a strange phenomenon I can't explain. I'm running an nginx with letsencrypt and an Java application server. The nginx listens on 443 and the application server on 8008. Both use SSL and the same cert. Nginx works like a charm, but the application server is strange:

[Try this URL](https://frascati.projectkeep.io:8008/openapi)

- Postman loads without an error
- CURL loads without an error
- Safari on macOS loads without an error
- Chrome on macOS loads the page, but the JavaScript fetch to `/openapi.json` fails - also [the direct download](https://frascati.projectkeep.io:8008/openapi.json)
- Firefox on macOS fails (can't establish secure connection)
- Safari on iOS fails

Using `curl -v --http1.1 https://frascati.projectkeep.io:8008/openapi/` shows:

```
curl -v --http1.1 https://frascati.projectkeep.io:8008/openapi/
*   Trying 18.218.218.93...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to frascati.projectkeep.io (18.218.218.93) port 8008 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=frascati.projectkeep.io
*  start date: Jan 27 13:46:16 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 13:46:16 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "frascati.projectkeep.io" matched cert's "frascati.projectkeep.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /openapi/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: frascati.projectkeep.io:8008
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 1394
< cache-control: public, max-age=86400
< last-modified: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 16:05:19 GMT
< date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 18:11:52 GMT
< content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< 
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Update**

For comparison here the nginx output for the [same content](https://frascati.projectkeep.io/openapi/):

```
 curl -v https://frascati.projectkeep.io/openapi/
*   Trying 18.218.218.93...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to frascati.projectkeep.io (18.218.218.93) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=frascati.projectkeep.io
*  start date: Jan 27 13:46:16 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 13:46:16 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "frascati.projectkeep.io" matched cert's "frascati.projectkeep.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /openapi/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: frascati.projectkeep.io
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.16.1
< Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 18:07:02 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 1394
< Connection: keep-alive
< accept-ranges: bytes
< cache-control: public, max-age=86400
< last-modified: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 16:05:19 GMT
< 
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Your application server chokes on TLSv1.3 proposals: `curl -v --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.3 <your_URL>` with a recent OpenSSL (1.1.0?). Can you add the TLS configuration of your application server?

Comment: Good hint. Have to upgrade curl on my macOS first. *sigh*. Be back shortly

Comment: Spot on @PiotrP.Karwasz - Can you turn your comment into an answer, so I can give your proper credit! TLS1.3 and JVM8 don't mix

Comment: Yes, `JSSE` on Java 8 does not support `TLSv1.3`, but it shouldn't disconnect if the client _proposes_ (not _requires_) version 1.3. I smell a bug somewhere. You can certainly provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: I tested with Java 8 and Tomcat 9: `curl` still sends a `TLSv1.3` proposal, but Tomcat chooses `TLSv1.2` and answers correcly. So your problem might be caused by a misconfiguration or application server bug. It is worth looking into it.

Comment: Yup - was my bad. I told the box: it's OK to answer TLS1.3 and then, due to the lack of support it terminates connection. You provided the right pointer. Make the comment into an answer for proper points attribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As came out in the comments to the question:

1. Your application server is using Java 8 with `JSSE`,
2. It has `TLSv1.3` configured among the possible TLS protocols.

The problem described is caused by the [lack of support for TLSv1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext) in Java's standard SSLContext implementation. So:

- `curl` proposes `TLS` up to version 1.3
- the server accepts, then chokes on it

**Remark**: If you are using Tomcat, the `OpenSSLImplementation` supports `TLSv1.3` if the underlying native library does.

Comment: Thx for your help. I removed the lines that had forced 1.3 and let the platform handle it